# Generate valid dictionary in Ansible with condition depends

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I want to generate valid dictionary in Ansible with condition depends for sending it by uli module (as json) and try to use Jinja2:

```yaml
    - name: set_fact
      set_fact:
        request_body:
          matchers: |
            {% if "myserver" in server__fqdn %}
            - name: "host"
              value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
              type: "EQUAL"
            - name: "node"
              value: "myserver"
              type: "EQUAL"
            {% else %}
            - name: "host"
              value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
              type: "EQUAL"
            {% endif %}
          teamName: "{{ server__team }}"

    - name: send data to endpoint
      vars:
        endpoint_url: "http://myendpoint.org"
      uri:
        url: "{{ endpoint_url }}/api/v1/data"
        body: "{{ request_body }}"
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "endpointKey {{ provision__endpoint_data_token }}"
        method: POST
      register: data_status
      ignore_errors: true
```

I checking type of generated var **request_body** with debug:

```yaml
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ request_body  }}"
          - "{{ request_body |  type_debug }}"
```

and it show valid dict:

```
TASK [provision : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
четверг 19 октября 2023  16:39:06 +0300 (0:00:00.078)       0:00:05.771 ******* 
ok: [56040] => 
  msg:
    matchers: |-
      - name: "host"
        value: "myserver.local"
        type: "EQUAL"
      - name: "node"
        value: "myserver"
        type: "EQUAL"
    teamName: superduper_team
  - dict
```

But task with sending var to endpoint failed:

```
TASK [provision : send data to endpoint] ********************************
четверг 19 октября 2023  16:39:06 +0300 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:05.810 ******* 
fatal: [myserver.local]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  connection: close
  content_length: '262'
  content_type: application/json
  date: Thu, 19 Oct 2023 13:39:07 GMT
  elapsed: 0
  json:
    code: 3
    details: []
    message: 'proto: syntax error (line 1:14): unexpected token "- name: \"host\"\n  value: \"myserver.local\"\n  type: \"EQUAL\"\n- name: \"node\"\n  value: \"myserver\"\n  type: \"EQUAL\"\n"'
  msg: 'Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request'
  redirected: false
  server: nginx
  status: 400
  url: http://myendpoint.org
  vary: Origin
...ignoring
```

But, when I do not use var generation it works:

```yaml
    - name: send data to endpoint
      vars:
        endpoint_url: "http://myendpoint.org"
        request_body:
          matchers:
            - name: "host"
              value: "myserver.local"
              type: "EQUAL"
            - name: "node"
              value: "myserver"
              type: "EQUAL"
      uri:
        url: "{{ endpoint_url }}/api/v1/data"
        body: "{{ request_body | to_json }}"
        body_format: json
        headers:
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Authorization: "endpointKey {{ provision__endpoint_data_token }}"
        method: POST
      register: data_status
```

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the YAML [block](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#812-literal-style) to the list. Use [filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#id11)

```yaml
  request_body:
    matchers: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% if "myserver" in server__fqdn %}
      - name: "host"
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: "EQUAL"
      - name: "node"
        value: "myserver"
        type: "EQUAL"
      {% else %}
      - name: "host"
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: "EQUAL"
      {% endif %}
      {% endfilter %}
    teamName: "{{ server__team }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    server__fqdn: myserver.local
    server__team: superduper_team

    request_body:
      matchers: |
        {% filter from_yaml %}
        {% if "myserver" in server__fqdn %}
        - name: "host"
          value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
          type: "EQUAL"
        - name: "node"
          value: "myserver"
          type: "EQUAL"
        {% else %}
        - name: "host"
          value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
          type: "EQUAL"
        {% endif %}
        {% endfilter %}
      teamName: "{{ server__team }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: request_body|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: request_body
    - debug:
        var: request_body|to_json
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml -l test_11

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  request_body|type_debug: dict

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  request_body:
    matchers:
    - name: host
      type: EQUAL
      value: myserver.local
    - name: node
      type: EQUAL
      value: myserver
    teamName: superduper_team

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  request_body|to_json: '{"matchers": [{"name": "host", "value": "myserver.local", "type": "EQUAL"}, {"name": "node", "value": "myserver", "type": "EQUAL"}], "teamName": "superduper_team"}'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

The next option is to create a dictionary

```yaml
  matchers_dict:
    true:
      - name: host
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: EQUAL
      - name: node
        value: myserver
        type: EQUAL
    false:
      - name: host
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: EQUAL
```

and select the attribute depending on the condition

```yaml
  matchers: "{{ matchers_dict['myserver' in server__fqdn] }}"
  request_body:
    teamName: "{{ server__team }}"
    matchers: "{{ matchers }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    server__fqdn: myserver.local
    server__team: superduper_team

    matchers_dict:
      true:
        - name: host
          value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
          type: EQUAL
        - name: node
          value: myserver
          type: EQUAL
      false:
        - name: host
          value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
          type: EQUAL
    matchers: "{{ matchers_dict['myserver' in server__fqdn] }}"
    request_body:
      teamName: "{{ server__team }}"
      matchers: "{{ matchers }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: request_body|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: request_body
    - debug:
        var: request_body|to_json
```

Optionally, use the filter *ternary*

```yaml
  matchers_dict:
    A:
      - name: host
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: EQUAL
      - name: node
        value: myserver
        type: EQUAL
    B:
      - name: host
        value: "{{ server__fqdn }}"
        type: EQUAL
  matchers: "{{ ('myserver' in server__fqdn)|
                ternary(matchers_dict.A, matchers_dict.B) }}"
```

Comment: Hm, I tried, but it not works on set_fact: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %} ; ): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: I fully copied your playbook(created test playbook), but it not works. I placed results here: https://pastebin.com/T3HzQ6Dn , maybe it ansible version problem(I included ansible --version output)?

Comment: I added the next option. Try this one if Jinja doesn't work for you.

Comment: Vladimir, second case(withous Jinja2) works, thanks!